# Format corrupted bootable Ubuntu-USB-Stick?

Tags: live-usb

I've made a USB-Stick to boot Ubuntu some fair time ago, sometime it got corrupted, idk what happened. Trying to boot it, it will send me into the recovery menu. Windows won't let me format the USB-Stick since it's readonly. How am I supposed to make it usable again? Is there anything I can do through the root shell prompt from the recovery menu?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it has gone read only there is a almost 100 percent chance its bad, nothing can be done with it..

Comment: do you have access to a PC running ubuntu? If not, this is a windows question and not for this site.

Comment: @24601 i am sure the problem might be only fixable through the root shell prompt anyways. Since that‘s not based on windows I would rather consider it a ubuntu question, lol.

Comment: Are you saying the data is corrupted, or are you saying the hardware is dying? If the data is corrupted, then wipe it and flash it with an up-to-date ISO. If the hardware is dying, replace it.  If you can't wipe it, and there's not a hardware read online switch, then it's probably dead/dying and you can't fix that.

Comment: You can analyze the problem according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035) and if you are lucky, find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If the hardware lock (if any) is unlocked, and if the operating system refuses to let you format the device...

...Then that hardware is dead.

Ubuntu cannot resurrect dead hardware.

Give it the moment of silence that it has earned from years of reliable work for you. Then throw it in the trash.